# Using DLL file in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made a media player using VB.net but if does not support some ile formats such as mkv,rmvb etc.

Is it possible to embed a mkv file dll in a vb.net program to run the media file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to embed a mkv file dll in a vb.net program to run the
>   media file?

Yes it is possible if the dll is designed to interface with .net.

I would suggest looking at the [VLC Api for .net](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC).  VLC runs most video formats.

Comment: Mind you. The program I've written is in VB.net. In the link which you have given there is mention of ONLY c#

Comment: Once it's compiled it doesn't matter what language it was written in.  Because it's made to interface with .net, any language in the .net family can use it.

Comment: I tried o add the dll by right clicking on solution explorer and clicking on add reference, then choosing the dll. But its giving an error that the DLL cannot be added. The name of the dll is libmkv_plugin.dll  Any other way to add the dll???

Comment: The dll's that come with vlc aren't compatible by themselves you need a .net wrapper to use them. You could make your own if you wish  Here's [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4zey12w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on doing that with VB